# Strapi API bullet points in description

Tags: api, strapi

I am new to Strapi but could not find an answer to this question when searching. I have Strapi deployed via Heroku and want to add a list of bullet points in my description. The goal is to fetch the description onto my website as bullet points. Is this doable? If so how?